# A synonym for 'à la carte' to describe additional services provided

Tags: synonyms, business-language

What is a synonym, specifically for business negotiation, to describe additional services provided (e.g. The following services will be offered *à la carte*:...)?

Comment: I think that *à la carte*, is precisely the expression you need. It is because there is no obvious English equivalent that *à la carte* is widely used outside of restaurants.

Comment: I respectfully disagree.  There must be a comparable term used in business contract negotiations.

Comment: You may refer to "optional services" or "contract options".

Comment: Then why not say *The following listed services are available separately as required*. What precise meaning of *à la carte* do you wish to convey?

Comment: How about "extra-cost options".

Comment: "For an additional fee". Straightforward. I don't know if "optional" necessarily implies an additional fee; if you're not sure you want to be paid for it, feel free.

Comment: "Individually priced services."

Comment: I agree with both medica and Brian.  "The following optional services are available for an additional fee."  "The following individually priced services are also available."

Answer (score 1):

*Optional* services.

They are not included by default. Choose them individually from the menu - they are not part of the set dinner.